# Filling the empty rows with the first row

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have tab delim file like follows:

```
a   12  17  bac 30  42
a   15  18
a   18  22
```

I would like to repeat the the column bac 30 42 to remaining rows like follows:

```
a   12  17  bac 30  42
a   15  18  bac 30  42 
a   18  22  bac 30  42
```

I tried following command `awk '{$4=$4; $5=$5;$6=$6; print}' file.txt` but it didnt do any modification to the file. how can I achieve this in awk.

Comment: what is the logic here? copy the first row penultimate and last column if some are missing? is this always the case or could it happen that just one column was missing?

Comment: @fedorqui I  just want copy the "bac  30 42" and fill it subsequent rows where there is no values.

Comment: @EdMorton I have started. Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: It's just silly to be doing what you're doing now though. You don't know enough yet to recognize a bad answer from a good answer so you're presumably walking away from these questions thinking you've learned something when in fact you've learned buggy code and/or anti-patterns. Take the currently accepted answer for example - completely the wrong approach but you've accepted it within minutes of posting your question before anyone got a chance to post the right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk -F"\t" -v OFS="\t" '$4!="" {four=$4; five=$5; six=$6} $0!="" {$4=four; $5=five; $6=six; print $0}' test.in
a 12 17 bac 30 42
a 15 18 bac 30 42
a 18 22 bac 30 42
```

Comment: It works but in case where there are only 2 rows, it fails. is it possible to put in for loop so that it automatically recognises number of rows and fills it according to that

Comment: You have en empty line in the end of your input file. Added `$0!=""` as a fix.

Comment: Yes you are right and i corrected it. It works fine.

Comment: why don't you say `NR==1 {four=$4; ...}` and then `NF<4 {print $0, four, ...}`?

Comment: In case there was more six-field records between the three-field records. This should work also: `awk -F"\t" -v OFS="\t" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[i]=$i; for(i in a) printf "%s%s", a[i],OFS; printf "%s", ORS}' test.in`

Answer (score 0):

A correct solution FWIW:

```
$ awk 'NR==1{n=split($0,d)} {for (i=1;i<=n;i++) printf "%s%s", (i>NF ? d[i] : $i), (i<n ? OFS : ORS)}' file
a 12 17 bac 30 42
a 15 18 bac 30 42
a 18 22 bac 30 42
```